# c# Dynamic casting a List

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection, casting

I have some legacy code where I'm trying to condense and remove alot of redundant repetition. I have a `List<MessageItemViewModel>` as a parameter to a method being called from an ASP.NET MVC POST action.  The actual list items will be a subclass of `MessageItemViewModel`, eg. `MessageItemA1ViewModel`. In the method being called this list was being cast like so:

```
switch (level1Code)
            {
                case "A1":
                    {
                        var list = messages.Cast<MessageItemA1ViewModel>().ToList();
                        file = printHelper.Print(list).Save(exportFormat);
                    }
                    break;
                case "A2":
                    {
                        var list = messages.Cast<MessageItemA2ViewModel>().ToList();
                        file = printHelper.Print(list).Save(exportFormat);
                    }
                    break;
                case "A3":
```

There's about 80 cases in all but I want to reduce it using a dictionary:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _messageItemMap = new 
    Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
        {"A1", typeof(MessageItemA1ViewModel)},
        {"A2", typeof(MessageItemA2ViewModel)},
        {"A3", typeof(MessageItemA3ViewModel)},
```

and cast the list items to the actual underlying type dynamically.
So I've followed examples on SO and the approach works well by declaring a static method and casting against an item in my list:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this object entity) where T : class
    {
        return entity as T;
    }
}


public class ExportHelper
{
    public byte[] GetFile(string level1Code, string title, List<MessageItemViewModel> messages, ExportFormat exportFormat)
    {
        .
        .
        .

        var castMethod = typeof(Ext).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).MakeGenericMethod(_messageItemMap[level1Code]);
        var anItemType = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { messages[0] });
```

`anItemType` is correctly of the actual type I'm casting to. In the immediate window when debugging a call to `anItemType is MessageItemA2ViewModel` returns true. BUT I need to cast all the items so I tried this:

```
var castMethod = typeof(Ext).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).MakeGenericMethod(_messageItemMap[level1Code]);
var theMessageItemModel = messages
    .Select(p => castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { p }))
    .Where(p => p != null)
    .ToList();
```

This initially seemed to work as hovering over `theMessageItemModel` debugging showed the values as the type I cast to, but that's just the magic of the Visual Studio tooling. Inspecting items in the immediate window as previously the items are actually defined as System.Object and also I see the return types of the Linq calls return `List<Object>`. This is an issue later because 
`theMessageItemModel` is passed to another library generic method where `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))` is called in order to determine the shape of the POCO to do some further processing. When passed in as a `List<Object>` 0 properties are found but if I can get the list passed in as one of the subclasses, eg. `List<MessageItemA1ViewModel>` then it will return properties.

Can anyone suggest how I should use my Cast RuntimeMethodInfo to create a correctly type List of the Type matching the level1Code in my Type dictionary?

===Update===
Actually one thing I didn't mention that because the library method I'm calling is generic I've had to reflect that as well to pass the dynamically cast type through to the Print method:

```
var printMethod = printHelper.GetType().GetMethod("Print").MakeGenericMethod(theMessageItemModel.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single());
var docRender = printMethod.Invoke(printHelper, new object[] { theMessageItemModel }) as IDocumentRender;
file = docRender.Save(exportFormat);
```

The `theMessageItemModel.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()` call is where `System.Object` is being found and passed through, because of my Linq call re-casting back to `List<System.Object>`

Comment: But at runtime you'll have the correct type. Probably the immediate window is resolving to compile type because `Invoke` method returns an `object`

Comment: It's been failing at run time because our library call is failing because when calling TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)) T is System.Object and I have an list of zero properties

Comment: But another problem, what will be the containing type of `theMessageItemModel`? you cannot have a list with heterogeneous type unless it's `object`,`dynamic` or an interface or a base class ...

Comment: Try to specify explicitly the type of `theMessageItemModel` as `List<dynamic>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I had a deeper think about the LINQ statement. Because at compile time what's coming back from my castMethod can't be known then the LINQ could only resolve as far as Object so I needed the List being enumerated to actually be able to be resolved when run.  So I realised I can push the LINQ into my Cast method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CastList<T>(this IEnumerable<object> entity) where T : class
{
    var ret = entity
        .Select(e => e as T)
        .ToList();

    return ret;
}
```

When calling this it returns for example `List<MessageItemA2ViewModel>` and now my call to `theMessageItemModel.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()` gives me the subclass type actually in the List so the Print method is called correctly:

```
var castListMethod = typeof(Ext).GetMethod("CastList").MakeGenericMethod(_messageItemMap[level1Code]);
var theMessageItemModel = castListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { messages });

var printMethod = printHelper.GetType().GetMethod("Print").MakeGenericMethod(theMessageItemModel.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single());
var docRender = printMethod.Invoke(printHelper, new [] { theMessageItemModel }) as IDocumentRender;
file = docRender.Save(exportFormat);
```

and 12 properties are found with `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))` and right at the end I get my expected output.